Get different errors sending form from frontend to backend (React (VITE), Node, Nginx)
Good day!
I am trying to send form data from React to Node and then use it to send an email using Nodemailer. Everything works perfectly on my PC when I run it locally, but when I deploy to the server I keep on getting different errors.
At first everything worked fine, the form was being sent successfully while using desktop browser, but did not work from mobile. Then I have noticed that in my React app I was still using http://localhost:8080 to send fetch() request. I have changed it to http://my-site's-IP:Node.js-port. The request got blocked, because of HTTP x HTTPS (error: Mixed content was loaded over https...).
I changed the URL to https://... and added app.use(cors()); to Node. It started throwing another error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. This time I went to Nginx configuration (sites-available [also linked with sites-enabled]) and edited it adding some lines and commenting others (here I use '//' istead of '#'):
server {
    root /website location/dist;
    server_name www.domain-name.com domain-name.com;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
** //   proxy_pass http://website-IP:REACT.JS PORT USED IN DEVELOPMENT/;
//      proxy_version 1.1;
//      proxy_set_header Host $host;
//      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;**
    }

    **location /apply {
        proxy_pass http://website-IP:Node.js-port/;
        proxy_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade'
        proxy_set_header Ho
    }**
}

I have also used certbot to add SSL certificate (which automatically modified Nginx configuration, see screen).
After the last modification I get another error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
I have read a number of articles some saying I need to find out a server port my React application is running on and use it in configuration file, as well as in cors() in Node.js file. Others say it is client-side problem and I just need to clean my browser's cache.
Right now I am really confused and don't know what steps to take.
Here is how I send the request from React:
const response = await fetch(
    `${formEndpoint}`, 
    {
        method  : 'POST', 
        body    : JSON.stringify(messageContent),
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }
);

Form attributes:
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
Part of backend on Node.js:
app.post('/apply', (req, res) => {

    
    const { firstName, lastName, company, userEmail, userPhone } = req.body;

    function sendEmail(firstName, lastName, company, userEmail, userPhone) {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host        :   'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
                port        :   587,
                secure      :   false,
                requireTLS  :   true,
                tls: {
                    ciphers :   'TLSv1.2'
                },
                auth: {
                    user    :   emailFrom,
                    pass    :   password,
                }
            });
    
            const configs   = {
                // letter config here
            };
    
            transporter.sendMail(configs, function(error, info) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return reject({message: `An error has occured`});
                }
                return resolve({message: 'Email has been successfully sent'});
            });
        });
    }

    try {
        sendEmail(firstName, lastName, company, userEmail, userPhone)
        res.status(200).json({msg: 'thx'})
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    }
});

I don't really have anyone around who can advice me on this issue, so you are my last hope (:
I appreciate you effort!

"I have changed it to http://my-site's-IP:Node.js-port"... shouldn't you be sending to nginx which then forwards it to your Node.js app?

changing the url from http to https doesn't add ssl layer, you have to change either front-end to http or back-end to https by adding ssl certificate to express

@YuvarajM no, that's what nginx is for. It does the SSL termination and forwards the request to Express
